# trying to create a trigger that check age from an insert and place into another table if less than 18

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Develop a trigger that will be placed on the marketing list table that will insert a record into the child table if the person's age is less than 18 once an insert is attempted.

SEE the code below:

```
Create Trigger on_insert_marketing_list
On marketing_list for insert
As
BEGIN
        Declare @Name varchar (100)
        Declare @Dob date
        Declare @Gender char(1)
        Declare @Parish VARCHAR(50)
        Declare @Mobile varchar(50)
        Declare @Provider varchar(50)
        Declare @age int

        Select @age = datediff(year,@dob,getdate())from inserted

        If (@age) < 18      
        BEGIN
        Insert Into Childlist values(@Name,@Dob,@Gender,@Parish,@Mobile,@Provider)
        END

End

insert into marketing_list (Name, Dob, Gender,  Parish,  Mobile, Mobile_Provider) values
('Kendrick Lamar', '3/4/2005','M','Kingston', '18764532345','LIME')
```

Comment: **BTW:** You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: As soon as the `INSERT` transaction has completed, this data is potentially out of date. Why not just query for persons under 18 at retrieval time? (Also, your trigger is broken for two reasons - you don't set most of the variables to anything, and your one use of `inserted` assumes a single row, which is not a good assumption)

Comment: Oh, and `DATEDIFF(year,dob,getdate())` doesn't give you someone's age - it would tell you that someone born on 31st December 2011 was 1 year old on 1st January 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the `ChildsList` table, why not this view:

```
CREATE VIEW ChildsList
AS
   SELECT
       Name,
       DOB,
        Gender,
       Parish,
       Mobile,
       Mobile_Provider
    FROM
        marketing_list
    WHERE
       DOB >= DATEADD(year,-18,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

This is a) always up to date, and b) Doesn't try to compute their age directly, and so doesn't have to fiddle around with getting that calculation right.

---

If you do still want the trigger, do it as:

```
Insert Into Childlist 
select Name,Dob,Gender,Parish,Mobile,Mobile_Provider
from
    inserted where DOB >= DATEADD(year,-18,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

but as I say, that's immediately out of date once the date changes.

This will correctly insert one row into the `ChildList` table for an insert like:

```
INSERT INTO marketing_list (Name, Dob, Gender,  Parish,  Mobile, Mobile_Provider) values
('Kendrick Lamar', '20050403','M','Kingston', '18764532345','LIME'),
('Phillip Lamar', '198550403','M','Elsewhere', '18764532346','ORANGE'),
```

Comment: ok this is the question: Develope a trigger that will be placed on the marketing list table that will insert a record into the child table if the person's age is less than 18 once an insert is attempted....Sorry i never made it clear before

Comment: @RoundRobin - I've updated my answer to show how to do it as a trigger, but as I say, you should never do this in a real system.

Comment: ok well am in school teacher gave as lab assignment thanks for heads up though

Comment: It does sound a bit like you would like us to do your homework?

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post my function that calculate the ages of someone :

```
create function [dbo].[CalculateAge] ( @p_BirthDate date, @p_ReferenceDate date )
returns int as
begin

  return DateDiff( Year, @p_BirthDate, @p_ReferenceDate ) - 
         ( Case When DateAdd( Year, DateDiff( Year, @p_BirthDate, @p_ReferenceDate ), @p_BirthDate ) > @p_ReferenceDate Then 1 Else 0 End )

end
```